# Adding leaves to tree models in opengl to improve realism

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, rendering

I'm newbee in opengl, and I'm not so familiar with the billboard techniques. Recently I have a project to make realistic tree models, I have rendered tree branches using **cylinders**, like below:  [image]

I'm satisfied with this look, but when I add leaves to the branches, I encountered problems. I'm not sure how to make it natural and realistic, I tried to use small leaf billboard and attach the billboard along the branches, the result is shown below:[image]

As you can see, it's really ugly and unnatural, so please give me some ideas on that, how can I attach the leaves to my branches in a correct way? Please make it more detailed because I'm really new to opengl.
**EDIT:**
I've implemented what I want. I've done that by attaching cross-billboards to the end nodes of tree. Each cross-billboard contains 3 billboards, the angle between any two billboard is 60 degress. And below is the result:
[image]

Comment: You should use a leaf texture with alpha blending.

Comment: Also, you need some smaller branches to attaches the leaves to. Otherwise they are too spread out...

Answer (score -1):

I guess, general approach in graphic techniques(this question is not about OpenGL, in fact) is to look around, understand the maths, implement them, optimize them. To get perspective at common and proved techniques used, read articles about state-of-art graphics stuff. NVidia has good series, called GPU Gems. More over, there is even an article about rendering realistic trees - [watch there](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch04.html)

When it comes to such particular question, how to place the leaves, it depends on the tree, you actually want to render. Okay, let's watch some marginal tree, like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V49jl.jpg

I suggest, that you build tree structure with some sort of fractal function. Try to tweak it in the way, that end-branches are more likely to grow up away from ground part. The leaves are also more likely to grow on the outer part of tree's volume and on the smaller branches. Play with values and watch the results. It's all about you. There is no recipe to succeed